# Is there a way to avoid N+1 queries when using a unidirectional @ManyToOne relationship in JPA + Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities:

**DummyA:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dummy_a")
@Data
public class DummyA implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "dummy_b_name", referencedColumnName = "name", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private DummyB dummyB;
}
```

**DummyB:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dummy_b")
@Data
public class DummyB implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "entity_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
}
```

As it currently stands, any attempt to fetch `DummyA` objects results in additional queries to fetch `DummyB` objects as well. This causes unacceptable extra delay due to N+1 queries and also breaks `Page` objects returned by `repository.findAll(specification, pageable)`, causing incorrect total page counts and element counts to be returned (in my case `repository` extends `JpaRepository`). Is there a way to do it such that DummyB objects are lazily loaded or, if that's not possible, so that they're all eagerly loaded in a single query?

Limitations:
I'm fairly new to JPA and Hibernate and have been learning how to use them. I've come across the following in a project I'm working on. I don't have the liberty to include new dependencies and my project currently does not allow hibernate bytecode enhancement through `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)`.

Things I've tried so far and did not work / did not work as expected:

1. `@ManyToOne(optinoal = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`
2. Tried to see if accessing the `dummyB` field in `dummyA` is what caused the N+1 queries by removing `dummyB`'s setter and getter. Still had N+1 queries.
3. Using `@EntityGraph` on `findAll`.
4. Tried implementing `PersistentAttributeInterceptable` and using `PersistentAttributeInterceptor` to solve the problem.

Links to resources I've looked up so far:

1. [@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) doesn't work on non-primary key referenced column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082281/manytoonefetch-fetchtype-lazy-doesnt-work-on-non-primary-key-referenced-co)
2. [N+1 query problem with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/n-plus-1-query-problem/)
3. [Hibernate lazy loading for reverse one to one workaround - how does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155452/hibernate-lazy-loading-for-reverse-one-to-one-workaround-how-does-this-work)
4. [PersistentAttributeInterceptable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/spi/PersistentAttributeInterceptable.html)
5. [JPA Entity Graph](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your entity definitions look off to me, as I don't see a collection defined in either of the two sides of the one to many relationship.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when I received the entities to work on them, the many-to-one relationship was defined as a unidirectional relationship from DummyA to DummyB. If I'm not mistaken, if it were bidirectional I'd end up having a Collection on the side of DummyB along with a one-to-many relationship, correct? (Side question: does a unidirectional many-to-one relationship even make sense?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come back with an answer in case anyone is curious. It turns out that some entries had an invalid "magic" value in the column used by `DummyA` as the foreign key to associate it with `DummyB`, causing Hibernate to execute separate queries for those null values in order to check if the association is truly not found (see [this doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html) and [this answer from a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11223478/16724595)). I mistook those queries as N+1. The project also had an interceptor that extended Hibernate's `EmptyInterceptor` in order to modify queries that produced pages, resulting in incorrect counts if secondary queries were executed.